# Jackson XML to JSON converter removes multiple child records

Tags: jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am using following code to convert my source XML to JSON. However, this code removes any multiple occurrence of child records in source XML and output JSON only contains last child record.

How do I get Jackson XML to JSON converter to output all child records in JSON?

**Code**

```java
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Map entries = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("source.xml"), LinkedHashMap.class);
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = jsonMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(entries);
System.out.println(json);
```

**Source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<File>
  <NumLeases>1</NumLeases>
  <FLAG>SUCCESS</FLAG>
  <MESSAGE>Test Upload</MESSAGE>
  <Lease>
     <LeaseVersion>1</LeaseVersion>
     <F1501B>
        <NEDOCO>18738</NEDOCO>
        <NWUNIT>0004</NWUNIT>
        <NTRUSTRECORDKEY>12</NTRUSTRECORDKEY>
     </F1501B>
     <F1501B>
        <NEDOCO>18739</NEDOCO>
        <NWUNIT>0005</NWUNIT>
        <NTRUSTRECORDKEY>8</NTRUSTRECORDKEY>
     </F1501B>
  </Lease>
</File>
```

**Actual Output**

```
{
  "NumLeases": "1",
  "FLAG": "SUCCESS",
  "MESSAGE": "Test Upload",
  "Lease": {
    "LeaseVersion": "1",
    "F1501B": {
      "NEDOCO": "18739",
      "NWUNIT": "0005",
      "NTRUSTRECORDKEY": "8"
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "NumLeases": "1",
  "FLAG": "SUCCESS",
  "MESSAGE": "Test Upload",
  "Lease": {
    "LeaseVersion": "1",
    "F1501B": [
      {
        "NEDOCO": "18738",
        "NWUNIT": "0004",
        "NTRUSTRECORDKEY": "12"
      },
      {
        "NEDOCO": "18739",
        "NWUNIT": "0005",
        "NTRUSTRECORDKEY": "8"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help shall be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get the solution to this problem by using [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212) API to convert source XML to [JSONObject](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/JSONObject.html) and then to JSON by Jackson API.

**Code**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

...
...

try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "source.xml"))) {
    String xml = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
    JSONObject jObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    Object json = mapper.readValue(jObject.toString(), Object.class);
    String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(json);
    System.out.println(output);
}

...
...
```

**Source XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<File>
  <NumLeases>1</NumLeases>
  <FLAG>SUCCESS</FLAG>
  <MESSAGE>Test Upload</MESSAGE>
  <Lease>
     <LeaseVersion>1</LeaseVersion>
     <F1501B>
        <NEDOCO>18738</NEDOCO>
        <NWUNIT>0004</NWUNIT>
        <NTRUSTRECORDKEY>12</NTRUSTRECORDKEY>
     </F1501B>
     <F1501B>
        <NEDOCO>18739</NEDOCO>
        <NWUNIT>0005</NWUNIT>
        <NTRUSTRECORDKEY>8</NTRUSTRECORDKEY>
     </F1501B>
  </Lease>
</File>
```

**Output**

```
{
  "File" : {
    "NumLeases" : "1",
    "FLAG" : "SUCCESS",
    "MESSAGE" : "Test Upload",
    "Lease" : {
      "LeaseVersion" : "1",
      "F1501B" : [ {
        "NEDOCO" : "18738",
        "NWUNIT" : "0004",
        "NTRUSTRECORDKEY" : "12"
      }, {
        "NEDOCO" : "18739",
        "NWUNIT" : "0005",
        "NTRUSTRECORDKEY" : "8"
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved by updating to Jackson version 2.12.x

If using maven the version could be updated adding this property to the pom.xml

```
<properties>
 <jackson-bom.version>2.12.4</jackson-bom.version>
</properties>
```

More details available here about library improvements - https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-improved-xml-b9487889a23f

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that XML does not have distinction between concepts of "Objects" (in JSON term, that is, collection of key/value pairs) and "Arrays" (ordered sequence of values without name). When using data-binding (POJOs), it is possible to determine from Java type which one a particular XML element means -- if Java property is a `List` or array, it has to be "Array"; otherwise "Object" -- but when only telling mapper to map XML to `java.util.Map` there is no such distinction, and default handling will essentially consider all XML Elements to indicate "Objects". And since "Objects" can not have properties with duplicate names, only one of the values (last one) is retained.

There is no simple way to avoid that using `XmlMapper`: you will need custom handling of some sort.

Comment: I understand the reason for this issue but can you share some ideas on how to do this custom handling? Do you know about any other Java library (for XML to JSON conversion) that can address this issue?

Comment: @Aman no, I do not think it is possible to reliably convert from XML to JSON without having actual understanding of structure -- XML and JSON have different data models, so you need to help with conversion. So better way in my opinion is to define actual Java classes to map XML content to, and then serialize instances as JSON. This allows proper handling of list/array values. Example given could be handled by Jackson as well as many other libraries (JAXB, XStream, JibX) -- in non-Jackson cases, you'd use those for XML, Jackson for JSON output.

Comment: I personally think that an XmlMapper that would "smartly" use arrays in those cases would be extremely convenient.